# Node.JS Smart Contract ERC-20 approve + transferfrom function not working

Tags: node.js, smartcontracts, web3js

I tried to do approve + transferFrom function in ERC-20 with web3js 
I got error  focus find below function  at  contract.methods.approve

```
       // File  ctest.js

        var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var path = require('path');
        var CONWeb3 = require('web3');
        var config = require('../etc/config.json');
        var web3 =  new CONWeb3("http://" + config.TKRPCSVR + ":" + config.RPCPORT ) ;
        var coinbase = {} ;


coinbase.tokenApproval = async function (reqSendAdress,reqApproveSend , reqTokenContract ,sendCrypt, approveAmonut  , callback) {

            var myAddress =  reqSendAdress ;
            var _spender = reqApproveSend  ;
            var _value = approveAmonut  ;
            var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);

            var abiArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './erc20_abi.json'), 'utf-8'));
            var contractAddress = reqTokenContract ;
            var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, {
                from: myAddress
            });
            var gasPriceGwei = 6;
            var gasLimit = 900000;
            var chainId = 9559;
            var rawTransaction = {
                "from": myAddress,
                "nonce": "0x" + count.toString(16),
                "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(gasPriceGwei * 1e9),
                "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
                "to": contractAddress,
                "value": "0x0",
```

/*
          **** below line generated  error ****
it not working it seem to be I miss something . or anyone have better way to 
fixed this  */

```
                "data": contract.methods.approve(_spender, _value).encodeABI(), 
                "chainId": chainId
            };

            var privKey = new Buffer( sendCrypt  , 'hex');
            var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
            tx.sign(privKey);
            var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

            try {
               var receipt = await  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
            }
            catch (err) {

                callback( "send error " + err  ,   null  );
                 return false ;
            }

                callback ( null , receipt ) ;
            balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call();
        } ///


    exports.coinbase=coinbase
```

END // Method

```
run > node caller.js  





var coinFunc = require("./ctest") ;

coinFunc.coinbase.tokenApproval (
                 "0xd1dc78f2865a7288a4a4b84272aaa5316cxxxxb" ,
                 "0x82378cf137F5dF4FA730529eB79a4583EA6xxxx" ,
                 "0xa70a8d416c22e5817323f2cebf233d929exxxx1" ,
                 "87b9fd1caa5e822063c4cd7e812edc0cd44xxxxb2ee0cdda8277a2d8ee"  ,
                 "1000" ,
                function ( err , res ){
                if (err) console.log("\n\n ================ERROR================\n\n" + err) ;
}) ;
```

===== error out come as below ====

```
------------------------
Attempting to send signed tx:  f8ac04850165a0bc00830dbba094a70a8d416c22e5817323f2cebf233d929e5722a180b844095ea7b300000000000000000000000082378cf137f5df4fa730529eb79a4583ea605fa900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8824ad2a0218213f4bdb07bde4e8fe3b7822d8cdc8228fbaae1eca6f541f4015f0403d296a0230dd25d52baf93085c5ec94cce16e60cf836f3c35ec7748b9e36c266c38163a
------------------------
 ++++++++++++ Send Error  +++++++++++++++

    Error: Returned error: known transaction: de721a1a73f1ea63d5597a75e47fbbfcd2fe4142fd81bdcca37892ddb4276c4a
        at Object.ErrorResponse (/opt/node2/Eth/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:16)
        at /opt/node2/Eth/node_modules/web3-core-
```